# How do you create a custom Policy AuthorizeAttribute in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization

I'm working on an intranet app(login by AD), which need authorize rights by users' department,title,or others information in AD.

In MS Docs, it seems that i should use Claims-based authorization(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

As you can image, some page should be authorized by different department, as the link said, what i can do is add several department Policies, but it's boring, because i have dozens of departments.

What can i do to implement like this or something else:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Department" , Value = "Finance")]
[Authorize(Policy = "Title" , Value = "VP")]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A [Custom Authorization Policy Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-2.2) might be a good option here. The docs suggest that it might be helpful if you need to use *a large range of policies (for different room numbers or ages, for example)* and you don't want to *add each individual authorization policy with an AuthorizationOptions.AddPolicy call.*.

Comment: thank you. if no others way.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [policy-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies).

A policy consists of one or more *requirements* which you can define by implementing the `IAuthorizationRequirement` interface. Then you create an `AuthorizationHandler<T>` where you validate the current context against the given requirement. In your case that is validating whether the current user is part of the required department specified in the `[Authorization]` attribute. If you want more control or have more specific authorization logic, you can implement a `IAuthorizationHandler` to handle multiple requirements at once.

I suggest you take a look at the documentation for implementing and registering policies with their requirements and handlers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Henk said, you can use an external policy-based framework such as [xacml](/questions/tagged/xacml) or [alfa](/questions/tagged/alfa). The end result is similar to what Henk wrote but it's policy-based rather than code-based (using `IAuthorizationRequirement`).

A policy looks like plain old English.

```java
policyset documents{
    target clause objectType == "document"
    apply firstApplicable
    policy employees{
        target clause user.role == "employee"
        apply firstApplicable
        /**
         * Employees can create documents in their own company
         */
         rule createDocument{
             target clause action.actionId=="create"
             condition user.company==resource.company
             permit
         }
         /**
          * Employees can delete documents they own
          */
        rule allowDelete{
            target clause action.actionId == "delete"
            condition user.userId == resource.owner
            permit
        }
    }
}
```

You then need to deploy the policy to your authorization engine / policy decision point and you invoke it from an interceptor within your app. Doing it this way keeps business logic (the app) separate from authorization logic (the policies). It also means that you can reuse the same policies / authorization across your apps no matter the language and across your stack (API, app, DB...)